# SDL_Events with no SDL window

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I want to use SDL to handle my events but I'm using OpenGL for graphics. Is there a way to use the event handleing of SDL even though I don't actually have any active SDL window?

Comment: Whatever you're using for the window should have pretty similar event handling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using OpenGL for graphics, you must have a window somewhere to contain the OpenGL canvas.  I very much doubt that you will be able to get any input from SDL's API's unless SDL is managing the window.  At least on Win32 systems, all input comes through the window message callback, so unless SDL is tied into that, it won't see any input messages at all.